# Trying to selectively forgo quotes when serializing a structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, data-structures, cfml

I am querying SQL and using that and ColdFusion [2018] to build a struct containing a JS schema.
After building the structure, I use serializeJSON and pass it to my JS [side note: Kendo UI].
Below is that resultant JSON that has been getting generated [approx]:

```
const dataModel = { id:"ID",
    "fields": {
        REPORTTITLE    : {
            nullable       : false,
            "hidden"       : false,
            type           : "string",
            template       : "reportTitleTemplate",
            filterable     : "{delay : 1500}" 
        },
        ISACTIVE       : {
            nullable       : false,
            "hidden"       : false,
            type           : "boolean",
            template       : "booleanTemplate",
            filterable     : true  
        },
        COLUMNGROUPING : {
            nullable       : false,
            "hidden"       : false,
            type           : "string"...and so on... 
        }
    }
};
```

The obvious problem I'm running into is two fold.
1st- For some reason the key *hidden*, and only *hidden*, is being quoted.  It is **possible** that this my fault due to some random 'fix' buried deep in a service, but I doubt it.  I can resolve this, I suppose.
2nd-[and this is my main concern]  I need a way to effectively signal that values for the key Template do not get quoted. The same goes for filterable when it is itself a struct.
I need the above to output as below instead:

```
const dataModel = { id:"ID",
    "fields": {
        REPORTTITLE    : {
            nullable       : false,
            hidden         : false,
            type           : "string",
            template       : reportTitleTemplate,
            filterable     : {delay : 1500} 
        },
        ISACTIVE       : {
            nullable       : false,
            hidden         : false,
            type           : "boolean",
            template       : booleanTemplate,
            filterable     : true  
        },
        COLUMNGROUPING : {
            nullable       : false,
            hidden         : false,
            type           : "string"...and so on... 
        }
    }
};
```

I abhor the thought of using ReReplace or the like.
Differentiating filterable values of true/false versus structs, I can work all of that out, "hidden" would be light enough if I *need* to do a replace on that alone.
I am just hoping that someone has run across this situation before and discovered something a little more elegant than a brute force replace for the template and filterable keys [or whatever key/value pair, obviously].
These reports do get **very** massive *and* I'm on a bit of a cycles/request vigilance kick...
Any input is appreciated, I've found practically another on this topic.

Comment: The question is unclear.  Yet, the dataModel const appears to be a Kendo datasource definition.  And that is processed by serializeJSON and the result sent to the client. Would need to see the actual json string that is produced (not the object) to understand the problem. I'd guess that the easiest solution would be to fix the json string when it is parse on the client side.  This could be done using a [JSON.parse receiver](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/php-js/json/reviver.php) function. These can be made to modify or remove properties from the received json.

Comment: @Yogi - You are absolutely correct.  I apparently married two JSON strings and then proceeded to butchered the result when typing the example.  It's been a while, do I clarify/correct with an edit or do I submit a follow up?  I assume it is the former.
{edit} Assuming the former, do I replace part(s) of the request that are misleading or categorically wrong? Or, do I leave all as it, and simply make an addendum?  Thx!

Comment: @Yogi  or whomever
I was WAY too in the weeds on debugging this and was focused on a CFML only solution.  The question is not only unclear...it's just dumb.  I feel obliged to delete it in its entirety and restate.  Etiquette dictates I proceed how?